# Power BI Lookupvalue fucntion has stopped working

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a Power BI report which uses the lookupvalue function which has been working fine and now it comes back with the error code of:

> A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected.

My code

`LOOKUPVALUE('Nil Stock'[NilTotal],'Nil Stock'[AsOfDate],'Failed Orders'[VisitDate],'Nil Stock'[ClientDesc],'Failed Orders'[ClientDesc])`

Why has it stopped working?

Comment: the result column has a variety of values and lookup can't decide which one you want. Check the table.

Comment: What do you mean variety of values? As both dates match and the clientdesc match on both so I don't know why the result column is stopping it from working

Comment: I mean that you have variety ofNilTotal   for some of VisitDate and ClientDesc.